# Replacing Views2 base field handler

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to add some rendering options to Views2 field handler (similar to 'Output this field as link' or 'Rewrite the output of this field') for a greater control over rendering of HTML markup (I need to add some extra attributes to tags). I want this additional options to be available for all (or at least most of the fields). Is it possible to replace default Views2 field handler (i.e. views_handler_field class) with my own field handler? There is a hook for submitting own handlers (hook_views_handlers) and there is a hook to tell other modules what handler should be used for given field (hook_views_data_alter). I also don't see a way to override default inheritance pattern for view_handler_field and its descendants. And extending every single field handler provided by other modules with my own classes seems to be pointless. Am I right saying that this cannot be the right way to solve this problem?

If I am right, what is another way to (1) extend field options form with some inputs and (2) alter rendering of this field based on inputs. I guess (1) could be achieved by altering form by default Drupal hook, but render method belongs to given field handler and I don't see a way to intercept its call and output altered markup.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use a non-existant hook_views_handlers_alter to change the path of a class which is somewhere